# How to format protein energy data from text file to matlab for scikit-feature algorithms

Tags: python, algorithm, scikit-learn, bioinformatics, scikits

i need to test some algorithms from [scikit-feature](https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature) and i want to use some datasets that are in text file, for example: [link](https://codeshare.io/GkmkJO)

I only know that the matlab files the algorithms use as input, are formated like this: the class is in a 'Y' array and the data in a 'X' array, here is some code to show just how they **open** and get the data from the .mat files:

Here is the [algorithm code](https://github.com/jundongl/scikit-feature/blob/master/skfeature/example/test_CFS.py)

```
#test_CFS.Py
mat = scipy.io.loadmat('../data/colon.mat')
X = mat['X']    # data
X = X.astype(float)
y = mat['Y']    # label
y = y[:, 0]
n_samples, n_features = X.shape
```

I tried to make a code to generate a mat file from my data in .txt, and the it was successfully processed by the algorithm i used (test_CFS.py), it didn't show any error with the [test file](https://codeshare.io/2EBrMp) i used with just 9 columns and 8 rows.

Here is my code to make a .mat file from a .txt

```
#textToMat.py

import numpy as np
import scipy.io as sio

file = open("matrix.txt", "r")
data = file.readlines()

Y = []
subY = []

X = []
subX = []

print len(data)
print len(data[0].split())

for i in range(len(data)):
    values = data[i].split()

    subY.append(np.array(float(values[0]),dtype=float))
    Y.append(np.array(subY))
    subY = []

    for j in range(1, len(values)):
        subX.append(np.array(float(values[j]), dtype=float))

    X.append(subX)
    subX = []

npY = np.array(Y, dtype=float)
npX = np.array(X, dtype=float)

sio.savemat('matrix.mat', {'Y':npY,'X':npX})
```

But then, when i tried to run the algorithm with the big mat file i generated it retuns me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_CFS.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_CFS.py", line 12, in main
    X = X.astype(float)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Yoy may ask why i append an array with one data to another array, that's because when i print the data from the scikit-feature's mat file it returns me this:

```
{'Y': array([[-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [-1],
       [ 1],
       [-1],
       [ 1]], dtype=int16), 'X': array([[ 2,  0,  0, ...,  0,  2, -2],
       [ 2,  2,  0, ...,  2,  0, -2],
       [-2,  2,  2, ..., -2, -2, -2],
       ..., 
       [ 0, -2, -2, ...,  0,  2, -2],
       [ 0,  0, -2, ...,  0, -2, -2],
       [ 0, -2, -2, ...,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int16), '__version__': '1.0', '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Mar 25 15:17:35 2015', '__globals__': []}
```

In my case i'm using float values.

Comment: I don't understand. I see no line `X = X.astype(float)` in your `test_CFS.py`?

Comment: The code i posted is to make a mat file for the algorithms that provides the scikit-feature because i only have text files, and the algorithm itself is the test_CFS.py, or do you mean that it needs the astype(float) in order to work? i assume that using np.array(X, dtype=float) does the work

Comment: No, I mean that from what I understand you run the code in block two `import numpy as np\n...` , and then you receive the given error. However, the error message says there is an error with the line `X = X.astype(float)`, but there is no such line in the code block. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You made an edit now, but I'm still not sure what you're saying. Please make sure to write the name of each file you're showing.

Comment: Yes, sorry if i wasn't clear, the test_CFS.py is the algorithm and the code i posted is for generating mat files from text files

Comment: So what code is the `test_CFS.py` code? Please _mark the code block_ with the correct file name.

Comment: Now i made a link to the original algorithm and put some labels

Comment: Recommendation for debugging: `print(X)` just before the error happens. Is the data what you would expect?

Comment: Yes, it returns me the matrix with all the data, the only strange thing it happens is that the data lost it's format, example: 4.094 to 4.09400000e+00

Comment: In the mat file, what are the expected types and dimensions of Y and X?
Also, do you mind reshaping the data before saving it to matlab?

Comment: @TocToc i posted a example of the shape of a mat file from scikit-feature's repository, and i'm trying to imitate it to be able to use my data instead of what they provide. What do you mean by reshaping the data? i do reshape it from a normal array to numpy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is wrong. For the numpy conversion all rows need to be of the same length. All your rows in the file you provided have 643 entries, **except row 232**, it has 644. Remove that row (or manipulate it accordingly) and your code should work fine.

Comment: Yes you were right, i didn't even expect it would be that because the data was given to me from my professor, that also explains why the test file didn't had any problem. Really thanks for the help!